# How to add borders in a report with Jasper Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I need make a report with a border like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to add the element "Line" in every band of your report. Add a "Line" on the side of every band and then on the top of the first band and on the bottom of the last band.

Then just put it with some color and raise the thickness of it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use iReport you can add a background-band and simply add there your borderlines